# Facebook API I get "Method Not Implemented" error, but it works if i put the url in a browser

Tags: php, facebook

When I call https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token I keep getting a return string that says “methed not iomplamented”
I’m calling it in php as follows
file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?my_ap_id&redirect_uri=http://www.besttechsolutions.biz/projects/facebook/index.phpclient_secret=MySecret458d628b1af&code=".$code);
I get
Method Not Implemented
Invalid method in request,
If I put the url in a browser, it worcks returning the code.  Why does it work in the browser, but not when I used the file_get_contents function????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your PHP function is doing a POST instead of a GET.  That's what Method Not Implemented usually means, that you're doing the wrong one.

When you put it in your browser it does a GET.